# django runserver error github fork

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, I mostly work in rails.  I just forked a friends project and am trying to get the server up and running.  I have installed all requirements and am running into the following error when i try to call runserver

```
└─(06:50 PM Fri Apr 12)─(22 files, 128b)─> ./runserver
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of       
<  django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at   
0x10c252f50>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
  line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in
  validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, 
in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in
get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in 
_populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in 
load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in   
import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/RobertZyskowski/Applebutter/calendezi/south/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from south.db import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
  File "/Users/RobertZyskowski/Applebutter/calendezi/south/db/__init__.py", line 78, in
<module>
    db = dbs[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
KeyError: 'default'
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have installed the same Django version as he was using?

Comment: I believe so but I will check, is there an equivalent to a Gemfile in django?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know ruby, but the version is very important in Django because different releases may not be backward compatible.

Comment: equivalent of gemfile would be a "requirements.txt" that some developers are putting in root of project. it can be used by "pip" to install all packages. also check if there is something like "DATABASES = { 'default': {" in your settings.py

Comment: I installed all the dependencies in the 'requirements.txt' file (including updating Django) and I am getting the same error

Comment: Your DATABASES in your settings.py is incorrect. There should be a database named 'default'.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Django to work, you have to provide settings to it. One of the required settings for Django to function normally is `DATABASES`. It should be provided as a Python dictionary and within that dictionary, Django looks for the `default` key. More about that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases).

The error you are getting means that Django does not have databases provided to it with the key `default`. There could be multiple reasons for that. One is that your settings file might not actually have the setting defined for various reasons (e.g. security). In that case all you have to provide that settings and the issue should be resolved. For a sample configuration of the setting, please refer to the link to the docs above. The second reason might be that you might have multiple settings files and you are not providing the correct settings file to the `runserver`. I noticed that you are not using the `manage.py runserver` command to start the server. If you will try that command, normally you can provide a `--settings` parameter:

```
manage.py runserver --settings=dot.notation.path.to.settings
```

Also if you are new to Django, please read the Django tutorial. It is very good and should get you started very well. The tutorial is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/).